# Continuous function approximated by a polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

I have to prove that:

> If $f$ is a real valued continuous function on the closed interval
>   $[a,b]$ then given $\varepsilon>0$  there is a polynomial $p(x)$ such
>   that $p(a)=f(a)$, $p'(a)= 0$ and $\left |p(x)-f(x)\right |<
>  \varepsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

I know every continuous function on closed and bounded interval is approximated by a polynomial. but how to construct such a polynomial which satisfies the given criterion? I am thinking of polynomial like $P(x) = f(a) + (x-a)^2 + (x-a)^3 + ...$

Does any one know what is the idea behind this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By translation, we may assume $[a,b]=[0,c]$ without loss of generality.
$ g(x)=f(\sqrt{x})$ is a continuous function on the interval $[0,c^2]$, hence by Weierstrass approximation theorem there is some polynomial $q(x)$ such that:
$$\forall x\in[0,c^2],\quad\left|g(x)-q(x)\right|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$$
hence:
$$\forall x\in[0,c],\quad \left|f(x)-q(x^2)\right|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{2},$$
but since $q(x^2)$ is an even polynomial, by taking $p(x)=q(x^2)+f(0)-q(0)$ we get $$p'(0)=0$$ as wanted, together with $p(0)=f(0)$ and $\left|p-f\right|\leq \varepsilon.$

Comment: very nice solution Jack!

Comment: @AdamHughes: thanks :)

Comment: @user145993: it would be nice, on your side, to accept at least some of the answers to the questions you posted on MSE - just use the power of the [grey tick](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/F/p/S/S/J/4/grey-checkmark-th.png).

Comment: ok sure i will try